# Test charge and Point charge

Tags: electrostatics, charge, terminology, definition

What is **a test charge**?
What is **a point charge**?
What is the difference between **a test charge** and  **a point charge**?

Comment: Have you tried googling this before asking it here?

Comment: Yes,I did not find the difference between test and point charge

Comment: Yeah, that actually is not a proper way to teach it, no idea why it's taught that way.

Answer (score 1):

A point charge is simply a charge distribution that has a value only at a single point.

A test charge is a point charge small enough that the charge distribution you're testing is not disturbed in any way.

Comment: What is a charge distribution?

Comment: I think there is no way to put this than to say: the way in which charge is distributed. Examples of charge distributions would be: charge that is spread over the surface of a sphere, charge that is spread through the volume of a cube, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A point charge with charge $q$ is the particular charge distribution $\rho(\vec{r})=q\delta^3(\vec{r})$. In other words, it's an element of charge with no volume.

A test charge is an imaginary point charge that you put in an electromagnetic field to investigate single-particle dynamics under the influence of the field.

Comment: The answer would be better if you'd explain what the delta is, too!

Comment: What's your math background? I need to know where to start.

Comment: Not mine, for the OP. I assume OP is starting out with electrostatics and hence has not come across the dirac delta yet

Comment: For future reference, this is the Dirac delta. But yes, I will revise if the OP agrees with you.